# Delphi Android App not starting with activated pushnotification

Tags: android-push-notification, delphi-11-alexandria

My android App will not starting since API > 30 and in googles play store the target api-level has to be greater then 30 for updates I am not able to make a app-update.
When I uncheck the flag "receive push notifications" in Options - Permissions, then the app is starting.
Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

I have found a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156964/android-app-written-by-delphi-keeps-stopping) but there was no clue to fix it.
I suspect it has to do with missing settings in the manifest file.